# Prevent Authenticated Users from accessing the inbuilt login form in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm using Django's default login form from within a custom template.However,once a user logs in using this form,they can still go back to the login form.Now,I'm aware of a method to prevent something like this from happening: decorators.
However,these decorators wont work on the way I'm rendering the login view.Have a look at the urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns=[
    path('',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/login.html')),
    path('home',views.home,name='home')
]
```

Normally,decorators are imported within views.py and called right above the view function.This can't be done here.
I dont know whether it will help,but here's the form part of  'main/login.html':

```
 <form method="POST" class="">
        {% csrf_token %}
       <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.username.label }}:
            {{ form.username }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.password.label }}:
            {{ form.password }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="login-input btn btn-warning" value="Login!" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this:

```py
...
urlpatterns=[
    path('',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/login.html')),
    path('home',views.home,name='home')
]
```

Try this:

```py
urlpatterns=[
    path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/login.html',
                                          redirect_authenticated_user=True)),
    path('home',views.home,name='home')
]
```